# NHibernate WARNING and the data is not saved

Tags: nhibernate

While I am saving by calling SaveOrUpdate(), I got this warning and the data is not saving in the database after calling Transaction.Commit().

> NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys - Unable
>   to determine if [project name] with
>   assigned identifier [primarykey] is
>   transient or detached; querying the
>   database. Use explicit Save() or
>   Update() in session to prevent this.

I am inserting a new object. Google search tell me to call Save() instead of SaveOrUpdate(): means Save() is only for inserting.

I search in Google and do not see much about this.
Could anyone give me suggestion for this problem or this warning?

Edit:
Here is the simulated sample mapping files -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly=""
                   namespace="">
    <class name="Customer" table="[dbo].[Customer]" optimistic-lock="none" >
        <id name="CustomerId" column="CustomerId" >
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="Name" /> 
        <property name="Age" column="Age" /> 
        <set name="CustomerDetails" cascade="none" inverse="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="CustomerId"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="CustomerDetail"/>
        </set> 
        <many-to-one name="MGender" fetch="select" cascade="none">
            <column name="GenderCode"/>
        </many-to-one> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
<class name="CustomerDetails" table="[dbo].[CustomerDetail]" optimistic-lock="none" >
    <id name="CustomerDetailId" column="CustomerDetailId" >
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Detail1" column="Detail1" /> 
    <many-to-one name="Customer" fetch="select" cascade="none">
        <column name="CustomerId"/>
    </many-to-one> 
</class>
```

```
<class name="MGender" table="[dbo].[MGender]" optimistic-lock="none" >
    <id name="GenderCode" column="GenderCode" >
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" column="Description" /> 
    <set name="Customers" cascade="none" inverse="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="GenderCode"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Customer"/>
    </set> 
</class>
```

Comment: Add the code where you're saving the object.

Answer (score 6):

You're using an assigned identifier so you need to set the unsaved-value attribute so that NHibernate can determine if an entity should be inserted or updated. Or you can explicitly call Save for new entities.

```
    <id name="CustomerId" column="CustomerId" unsaved-value="???" >
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are using a custom id, ie not using Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned() and you do not have any version or timestamp columns, there is no way NHibernate would know if thuis is a new row or an existing one. So, I fixed my problem by using GeneratedBy.UuidString(). Works like a charm. Almost put my code into production with this error message, fortunately my information was being saved.